# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range with Dynamic Array

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to add a value to a dynamic array but keep getting a run-time error with this.  I've found a few different sources saying that this should be the answer, so I cant figure out what I have done wrong...

```
Sub addtoarray()

    Dim catSheets() As String

    ReDim Preserve catSheets(UBound(catSheets) + 1)
    catSheets(UBound(catSheets)) = "Chemicals"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

When you create the `catSheets()` array, it's dimensionless. Therefore, you cannot use `UBound()` to determine the array's upper boundary.

You can certainly follow up a `Dim ()` with a `ReDim` if you want to specify an array size, but you won't be able to query the array dimensions until after you've given it some.

So you have a few options. First, you could follow up your `Dim ()` with an immediate `ReDim` to give your array an initial size:

```
Dim catSheets() As String
ReDim catSheets(0) As String
...
ReDim Preserve catSheets(...) As String
```

Or, you could just use `ReDim` from the start to assign an initial size and still have the ability to `ReDim` later:

```
ReDim catSheets(0) As String
...
ReDim Preserve catSheets(...) As String
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Array()` function and store it as a `Variant`. Done this way, you *can* query the `UBound()`. For example:

```
Dim catSheets As Variant
catSheets = Array()
Debug.Print UBound(catSheets)   ' => -1

ReDim Preserve catSheets(UBound(catSheets) + 1)
catSheets(UBound(catSheets)) = "Chemicals"   ' Works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `Variant` if you want to preserve the way to use the code.

```
Sub addtoarray()
    Dim catSheets As Variant
    catSheets = Array() ' Initially Empty (0 to -1)
    Redim Preserve catSheets(Ubound(catSheets) + 1) ' Now it's 0 to 0
    catSheets(Ubound(catSheets)) = "Chemicals" ' index here is 0
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't `ReDim` a `Variant`. You need to use the `Array()` function to _create_ an array first.